# How to add condition check in setInterval function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

For example, the JavaScript code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var val = 0;

            var p2 = setInterval(function(){proc2()},1000);
            function proc2()
            {
                // while (val == 0);
                alert(val);
                clearInterval(p2);
            }

            var p1 = setInterval(function(){proc1()},1000);
            function proc1()
            {
                val = 1;
                clearInterval(p1);
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

In function `proc2()`, I want to have it executed when the value of `val` is set to 1. So, I add the `while(val==0);` line, but it doesn't work. The browser get stuck. What's the problem with it? And what's the correct way to add condition check in setInterval function in JavaScript?

Comment: A bit unclear what you want. Do you want `proc2()` to run when `val == 1` or you call the function different times and the `clearInterval(p2);` runs only when `val == 1` ?

Comment: @Sergio when `val == 1`

Comment: OK, but you don't answer my question: run the function if val == 1 or the function runs all the time and the content of the function only runs when val == 1?

Answer (score 0):

It gets stuck in the while loop. Use return instead in the setInterval to preent the code from executing unless the condition was met.

The issue with while is that it keeps cycling through and never leaves the loop, freeing the thread for any other calls.

Comment: Just in case you use jQuery you might benefit greatly from [jQuery timers](https://github.com/adrenalin/jquery.timers) which offers a great abstraction layer for intuitive use of setInterval and setTimeout, with greatness of simple stopTime and labels for your timers.